# How do you increment file name in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to save a lot of data that needs to be separated in to different files like so
data_1.dat
data_2.dat
data_3.dat
data_4.dat

how do I implement this in python?

Comment: It probably is an overkill for simple use cases, but I wrote a small python library to do this in a thread-safe and overwrite-safe manner: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/seqfile

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for i in range(10):
    filename = 'data_%d.dat'%(i,)
    print filename
```

Comment: It does not need to be a singleton tuple. You can have `filename = 'data_%d.dat' % i`

Comment: I got into the habit of creating singleton tuples for format strings to remove syntactic ambiguities. i.e. `print '%d'%(i,), s`. It also makes it more clear when you want to not print a newline. But yes, `% i` would also work.

Comment: I understand. I guess for sheer clarity, this would be more understandable to me: `print '{:d} {}'.format(i,s)` as the equivalent but wordier version of your example....

Answer (score 13):

```
from itertools import count
filename = ("data_%03i.dat" % i for i in count(1))
next(filename)
# 'data_001.dat'
next(filename)
# 'data_002.dat'
next(filename)
# 'data_003.dat'
```

Comment: You deserve +10 for writing this as a generator using `itertools` ;)

Comment: @delnan: Come on, it's not *that* great :)

Comment: @ncoghlan: I don't agree that a generator function would be more appropriate, at least not without knowing more about the context which this will be used in.  Any reasons for your statement?

Comment: The same reason named functions are preferable to lambdas: they can be given a docstring, better support introspection, are easier to find from a stack trace, etc. If they aren't being created and consumed in a single step, it's generally worth taking the extra line or two to give them a proper name.

Comment: @ncoghlan: Generally true, but does not seem to apply to this case.  You wouldn't really want a docstring or introspection for this simple example.  I think readable would actually suffer when making this a generator function.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to generalise the filename generator to make it worthwhile (see my separate example). I had also forgotten the detail that a generator expression gives you the generator iterator directly, skipping the generator function step, so consider my comment withdrawn.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Sven's solution, but upgrading to a full generator:

```
from itertools import count
def gen_filenames(prefix, suffix, places=3):
    """Generate sequential filenames with the format <prefix><index><suffix>

       The index field is padded with leading zeroes to the specified number of places
    """
    pattern = "{}{{:0{}d}}{}".format(prefix, places, suffix)
    for i in count(1):
        yield pattern.format(i)

>>> g = gen_filenames("data_", ".dat")
>>> for x in range(3):
...     print(next(g))
... 
data_001.dat
data_002.dat
data_003.dat
```

Comment: As Sven rightly noted in the comments on his answer, this isn't worth doing in the simple case - only upgrade to a full generator if the additional flexibility is of value.

Answer (score 0):

If you go the itertools way, why mix it with a generator expression?

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> fngen= it.imap("file%d".__mod__, it.count(1))
>>> next(fngen)
'file1'
```