# How to apply n-times a function with map

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, lambda, functional-programming

I am starting to learn how to use python in a functional way and I am facing a problem I can't solve.

I have the following code (take in part from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5072008/4525192)) which does exactly what I want:

```
url = "www.testpage.com/"
def gen_url(prefix, suffix, places=3):
    pattern = "{}{{:0{}d}}{}".format(prefix, places, suffix)
    for i in count(1):
        yield pattern.format(i)

list_of_urls = []
for c in "xyz":
    g = gen_url(url+c,"&show=more")
    for x in range(2):
        list_of_urls.append(next(g))
```

And it generates something like this:

```
www.testpage.com/x001&show=more
www.testpage.com/y001&show=more
www.testpage.com/z001&show=more
www.testpage.com/x002&show=more
www.testpage.com/y002&show=more
www.testpage.com/z002&show=more
```

As you can see, It stops at 002 because of:

```
    ...
    for x in range(2):
        list_of_urls.append(next(g))
    ...
```

All the time I start with an empy list, use a for loop and fill it. I am trying to use map in this way and get rid of the for loop:

```
urls = map(lambda x:next(gen_url(url+x,"&show=more")),"xyz")
```

And it works. But I can only get to 001. Let's assume I want to reach 002; I am trying something like the following, but It doesn't work:

```
urls = imap((lambda x:next(gen_url(url+x,"&show=more")),"xyz"),2)
```

And this as well doesn't work:

```
urls = map((lambda x:next(gen_url(url+x,"&show=more")),"xyz"),repeat(2))
```

Could somebody explain me how to properly use the iterators in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally it would look like this:

```
def gen_url(prefix, suffix, id, places=3):
    pattern = "{}{{:0{}d}}{}".format(prefix, places, suffix)
    return pattern.format(id)

url = "www.testpage.com/"
a = [ gen_url(url + l, "&show=more", n) for l in "xyz" for n in range(1,4) ]
print a
```

So now your `gen_url` is a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) that accepts everything from outside.

And your're generating a cartesian product (basically all permutations) of 2 sequences `"xyz"` and `[1, 2, 3]`

The script above generates:

```
['www.testpage.com/x001&show=more',
 'www.testpage.com/x002&show=more',
 'www.testpage.com/x003&show=more', 
 'www.testpage.com/y001&show=more', 
 'www.testpage.com/y002&show=more', 
 'www.testpage.com/y003&show=more', 
 'www.testpage.com/z001&show=more',
 'www.testpage.com/z002&show=more',
 'www.testpage.com/z003&show=more']
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Just for future reference: do you have any suggestion for doing this the way I was trying? I mean, how to repeat with map?

Comment: I don't think you can easily do that with a single map over `"xyz"`

Answer (score 1):

Prefix and suffix are detracting from the simple logic in gen_url.
They can be pulled out.

Try this:

```
from itertools import count, islice

def gen_url(places=3):
    for i in count(1):
        yield "{{:0{}d}}".format(places).format(i)

url = "www.testpage.com/"
list_of_urls = [url+c+x+"&show=more" for c in "xyz" for x in islice(gen_url(), 0, 2)]
```